git diff ~usera/my_dir1 ~userb/my_dir2 includes all untracked files
git diff tag1 tag2 only looks at tracked files.
git diff ~usera/my_dir1 ~userb/my_dir2 includes all untracked files in my_dir1 and my_dir2. (~usera does not share the same .git-dir with ~userb).
Is there an option, so git will treat
git diff ~usera/my_dir1 ~userb/my_dir2 similar to git diff tag1 tag2 and only look at tracked files?
(And git diff tag1 tag2 is a bit misleading: I also want to see changes that are not committed yet - but limited to tracked files).
Imperfect workaround - but illustrates wanted behaviour:
parallel 'cd {} && git ls-files' ::: $dirA $dirB | sort -u |
  parallel diff -Naur $dirA/{} $dirB/{} | less

Edit
Workaround as small script: https://git.data.coop/tange/tangetools/src/branch/master/gitdiffdir/gitdiffdir


~usera does not share the same .git-dir with ~userb


so these are two separate repos?


@IvanBalepin Yes (they share the same ancestor).

What's wrong with the parallel diffs? It looks like you've got diffs of exactly what you want compared. You could even git diff $dirA/{} $dirB/{}.

@jthill Corner cases. Let $dirA contain a newline (\n) for example.

I think your "workaround" is the way to go. If you want to compare the content of two versioned contents, another way could be to import both histories in one single repo, and compare from that repo.

The import can even share object dbs, git clone -s --bare --no-tags --reference one/repo the/other `mktemp -d`; cd $_; git diff $(git -C one/repo rev-parse @) $(git -C the/other rev-parse @), the setup takes milliseconds, that clone of two linux repos is 56KB. Not a typo: 56KB.

git does not operate across repositories like you seem to think. The canonical way would be that you fetch the head commit of one repository into the other than run a git diff FETCH_HEAD.
